# SQL Query to return maximums over decades

Tags: mysql, sql

**THIS IS USING MYSQL**
My question is the following. I have a baseball database, and in that baseball database there is a master table which lists every player that has ever played. There is also a batting table, which tracks every players' batting statistics. I created a view to join those two together; hence the `masterplusbatting` table. 
  I now want to find the highest HR hitter in each decade since baseball began. Here is what I tried.

```
    select f.yearID, truncate(f.yearid/10,0) as decade,f.nameFirst, f.nameLast, f.HR
    from (
    select yearID, max(HR) as HOMERS
    from masterplusbatting group by yearID
    )as x inner join masterplusbatting as f on f.yearID = x.yearId and f.HR = x.HOMERS
    group by decade
```

You can see that I truncated the yearID in order to get `187, 188, 189` etc instead of `1897, 1885,`. I then grouped by the decade, thinking that it would give me the highest per decade, but it is not returning the correct values. For example, it's giving me Adrian Beltre with 48 HR's in 2004 but everyone knows that Barry Bonds hit 73 HR in 2001. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: you will need to group by 'decades' not years.  this may be a data issue - or you need to do more math on the dates first

Comment: What type of SQL is this?  The available functions are different for different vendors and implementations...

Comment: Off-topic, but 'everyone knows that Barry Bonds hit 73 HR in 2001' seems rather optimistic to me (especially considering the audience here)

Comment: Duly noted. :) I'll think before I post next time.

Comment: The name of that view is *almost* unintentionally hilarious.

Comment: I know right!? My friend and I had a good laugh over that.

Comment: Note that you could also truncate like this: `f.yearid DIV 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Lookup.DecadeID,
  Data.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    truncate(yearid/10,0) as decadeID,
    MAX(HR) as Homers
  FROM
    masterplusbatting
  GROUP BY
    truncate(yearid/10,0)
)
  AS lookup
INNER JOIN
  masterplusbatting AS data
    ON  data.yearid >= lookup.decadeID * 10
    AND data.yearid <  lookup.decadeID * 10 + 10
    AND data.HR     =  lookup.homers
```

Editted for MySQL

Comment: Sorry, I guess this doesn't help me because I don't think WITH works in MySQL. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @abrahamlincoln : Editted for MySql.  Still on iPhone apologies if any typos, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be aggregating by the wrong thing.  Somewhere, I expect to see a group by based on the player.

```
select truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0) as decade, mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast, sum(mpb.HR) as HRs
from masterplusbatting mpb
group by truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0), mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast
```

This gives the total number of home runs in each decade.  Now, you want the person with the most.  For this, I would use the `row_number()` function and subqueries:

```
select decade, nameFirst, nameLast, HRs
from (select decade, nameFirst, nameLast, HRs,
             row_number() over (partition by decade order by HRs desc) as seqnum
      from (select truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0) as decade, mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast, sum(mpb.HR) as HRs
            from masterplusbatting mpb
            group by truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0), mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by 1
```

In a database such as MySQL, you need to do this with a second join:

```
select t.*
from (select truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0) as decade, mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast, sum(mpb.HR) as HRs
      from masterplusbatting mpb
      group by truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0), mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast
     ) t join
     (select decade, max(HRs) as maxHRs
      from (select truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0) as decade, mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast, sum(mpb.HR) as HRs
            from masterplusbatting mpb
            group by truncate(mpb.yearid/10, 0), mpb.nameFirst, mpb.nameLast
           ) t
      group by decade
     ) tsum
     on t.decade = tsum.decade and t.HRs = tsum.maxHRs
order by decade
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am new to mysql and don't know anything about `row_number() over` and it is giving me a syntax error. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: MySQL, and sorry for not pointing that out in the original question.

Comment: Oh, that's the one database that does not support the ranking functions.  Alas.

Comment: It's still giving me some syntax errors on the `tstum.maxHRs`. I'll play around with it a bit and see if I can get it working. Thanks a bunch.