# SQL. Finding the average between certain dates

Tags: sql, syntax, database, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to find the average score received by films between a certain time

```
SELECT SUM (score * ?) / SUM(?) AS AGGSCO
  FROM movie, casting
       INNER JOIN casting
 WHERE movie.id = casting.movieid
       AND yr BETWEEN 1930 AND 1939;
```

Instead of the question marks, I think I would need the number of occurrences. Following this I would need to repeat the code to find the average between 40 and 49 and then 50 to 59. Is there a loop that I can use or would I need to rewrite the code? Thanks for any advice!

ps: I'm using squirrel, not mysql so the syntax may differ

Comment: Squirrel is just a client not a server software. You are likely using MySQL as DBMS and Squirrel as an application to access the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(score) / count(*) as AverageScote
from ...
```

or even better

```
select avg(score)
from ...
```

Comment: very simple,can't believe I missed that. Another simple question, to get the average for the next year                           select AVG(score), AVG(score)
FROM movie
WHERE yr between 1930 AND 1939;

Comment: Do i need to use the AS keyword

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

```
SELECT avg(score) AS AGGSCO, truncate(yr/10,0) AS DECADE
  FROM movie, casting
       INNER JOIN casting
 WHERE movie.id = casting.movieid
 GROUP BY truncate(yr/10,0)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904097/sql-query-to-return-maximums-over-decades).